# Ajuda com tela de pesquisa

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A query que monta a tela é a seguinte :

```
public List<Produto> listarProdutosDoGerenteRegional() {
    try {
        return manager.createQuery(" select p from Produto p where p.gerenteFilial.chefe.codigo =:codigo", Produto.class)
                .setParameter("codigo", usuario.getCodigo()).getResultList();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Gostaria de colocar o campo gerentefilial um ao lado do outro e as suas respectivas quantidades também. os outros campos continuariam.

```
<p:dataTable id="previsaosTable"
    value="#{previsaoGerenteRegionalBean.previsoes}" 
    var="produto"
    style="margin-top: 20px" 
    emptyMessage="#{msg.nenhum_tecnico}"
    paginatorPosition="bottom" 
    rows="5" 
    paginator="true"
    paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink}"
    currentPageReportTemplate="(#{msg.pagina} {currentPage} #{msg.de} {totalPages}) - (#{msg.registro} {startRecord} #{msg.a} {endRecord}) - Total ({totalRecords} #{msg.registros})"
    styleClass="mystyle" 
    paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="10, 20, 30">

    <f:facet id="header" name="header">
        lista de Historicos
    </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText=" Codigo do Produto"
        sortBy="#{produto.codigoProduto}"
        style="text-align: center; width: 140px">
        <h:outputText value="#{produto.codigoProduto}">

        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText=" Descrição"
        style="text-align: center; width: 140px">
        <h:outputText value="#{produto.descricao}">

        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText=" Gerente Filial"
        style="text-align: center; width: 140px">
        <h:outputText value="#{produto.gerenteFilial.nome}">

        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText=" Valor"
        style="text-align: center; width: 140px">
        <h:outputText value="#{produto.valor}">

        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>


    <p:column headerText=" Quantidade"
        style="text-align: center; width: 140px">
        <h:outputText value="#{produto.quantidadeRecente}">

        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText=" Receita da Previsão"
        style="text-align: center; width: 140px">

        <h:outputText value="#{produto.quantidadeReais}">
            <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                maxFractionDigits="2" />
        </h:outputText>

    </p:column>


    <p:column style="width: 100px; text-align: center"
        headerText="#{msg.acoes}">

        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="#{msg.excluir}"
            oncomplete="confirmacaoExclusao.show()" process="@this"
            update=":frmPesquisa:confirmacaoExclusaoDialog">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener
                target="#{pesquisaHistoricosBean.previsaoSelecionado}"
                value="#{tecnico}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Cara, dá pra explicar melhor tua dúvida? Tá muito vaga

Comment: Eu não entendi a dúvida

Comment: gostaria de colocar no titulo da lista GERENTE FILIAL 1 e abaixo a sua quantidade ao lado GERENTE FILIAL 2 e abaixo a sua respectiva a coluna seguinte o somatório das duas quantidades e a ultima coluna a multiplicacão entre a soma das quantidades e a coluna valor