# Ajuda com query JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Estou tentando fazer o retorno de uma query de grupo junto com a entidade produto retornando todos o dado da tabela produto e o somatório da quantidade. Recebo um erro que é o seguinte:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for TypedQuery [br.com.previsao.model.Produto] is incompatible with query return type [class java.lang.Long]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.resultClassChecking(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:387)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:344)
at Teste.main(Teste.java:30)
```

O código da query é a seguinte:

```
        String jpql1 = "select p, sum(p.quantidadeRecente) from Produto p where p.gerenteFilial.chefe.codigo =:codigo";

        //

        // metodo buscarPorPaginacao
        TypedQuery<Produto> query = manager.createQuery(jpql1, Produto.class);
        query.setParameter("codigo", 3L);
        List<Produto> produtos = query.getResultList();
        for (Produto prod : produtos) {
            System.out.println(" Impressão Produto da Empresa: ");
            System.out.println(" Nome : " + prod.getDescricao() + "Valor" + prod.getValor() +"Gerente" +prod.getGerenteFilial().getChefe().getCodigo()
                    + "Quantidade" + prod.getQuantidadeRecente()+ "Filial" + prod.getGerenteFilial().getNome());

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta retirar o `, sum(p.quantidadeRecente)` da sua JPQL.

A soma da quantidade recente de produtos pode ser computada depois assim:

```
long quantidadesRecentes = produtos.stream().mapToLong(Produto::getQuantidadeRecente).sum();
```

Em Java 7:

```
long quantidadesRecentes = 0L;
for (Produto p : produtos) {
    quantidadesRecentes += p.getQuantidadeRecente();
}
```

Comment: Estou usando o java 7. possui esta funções?

Comment: @user2509556 Feito

Comment: adicionei ao projeto o java 8 e funcionou . Dá para fazer o memo com um campo calculado produto.getValor * quantidadesRecentes ?

Comment: @user2509556 Se todos os produtos da lista tiverem o mesmo valor, dá sim. Entretanto, se os valores puderem variar, aí não tem escapatória que não seja somar todos eles.

Comment: vi que não posso fazer esta solução porque quero colocar em uma lista 
 ver https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215761/ajuda-com-tela-de-pesquisa